# How can I access information from one conditional and use it later in a different conditional?

Tags: c#, loops, conditional-statements

I'm trying to access the answer from an equation (BMR)

```
if(gender == "F")  
{   
    BMR = 655+(4.35 * weight) + (4.7 * height) - (4.7 * userAge );
}  
else if(gender == "M")  
{   
    BMR = 66+(6.23 * weight) + (12.7 * height) - (6.8 * userAge); 
}   
Console.WriteLine (name + " you entered: \nHeight: " + height + "\nWeight: " + weight + "\nAge: " + userAge + "\nGender: " + gender); 
Console.WriteLine ("Your BMR is " + BMR);
```

and use it here

```
static void ProcessChoice (int c)
{   
    double allowedCalories;
    if (c == 1) {
        allowedCalories = BMR * 1.2;
        Console.WriteLine ("Your allowed calories is " + allowedCalories);
    } else if (c == 2) {
        allowedCalories = BMR * 1.375;
        Console.WriteLine ("Your allowed calories is " + allowedCalories);
    } else if (c == 3) {
        allowedCalories = BMR * 1.55;
        Console.WriteLine ("Your allowed calories is " + allowedCalories);
    } else if (c == 4) {
        allowedCalories = BMR * 1.725;
        Console.WriteLine ("Your allowed calories is " + allowedCalories);
    } else if (c == 5) {
        allowedCalories = BMR * 1.9;
        Console.WriteLine ("Your allowed calories is " + allowedCalories);
}
```

But I keep getting errors.

Here's the entire code:

```
using System;

namespace Manning_C__10_23_17_Lab_Five
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string name;  
            double height, weight;   
            int userAge;  
            string gender;  
            double BMR = 0; 

            Console.Write("Enter your name: ");  
            name = Console.ReadLine ();  
            Console.Write("Enter your height in inches: ");  
            height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine ());  
            Console.Write ("Enter your weight in pounds: ");  
            weight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine ());  
            Console.Write ("Enter your age: ");  
            userAge = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine ());  
            Console.Write ("Enter your gender as M or F ");  
            gender = Console.ReadLine ();  
            gender = gender.ToUpper(); 

            if(gender == "F")  
            {   
                BMR = 655+(4.35 * weight) + (4.7 * height) - (4.7 * userAge );
            }  
            else if(gender == "M")  
            {   
                BMR = 66+(6.23 * weight) + (12.7 * height) - (6.8 * userAge); 
            }   
            Console.WriteLine (name + " you entered: \nHeight: " + height + "\nWeight: " + weight + "\nAge: " + userAge + "\nGender: " + gender); 
            Console.WriteLine ("Your BMR is " + BMR); 

            int choice;
            do {
                PrintMenu ();
                choice = Int32.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
                ProcessChoice (choice);
            } while (choice !=6);
            Console.WriteLine ("Thanks for using this system");
        }

        public static void PrintMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main Menu");
            Console.WriteLine("1. You don't exercise");
            Console.WriteLine("2. You engage in light exercise one to three days a week");
            Console.WriteLine("3. You exercise moderately three to 5 times a week");
            Console.WriteLine("4. You exercise intensely six to seven days a week");
            Console.WriteLine("5. You exercise intensely six to seven days a week " +
                "and have a physically active job");
            Console.WriteLine ("6. QUIT");
        }

        static void ProcessChoice (int c)
        {
            double allowedCalories;
            if (c == 1) {
                allowedCalories = BMR * 1.2;
                Console.WriteLine ("Your allowed calories is " + allowedCalories);
            } else if (c == 2) {
                allowedCalories = BMR * 1.375;
                Console.WriteLine ("Your allowed calories is " + allowedCalories);
            } else if (c == 3) {
                allowedCalories = BMR * 1.55;
                Console.WriteLine ("Your allowed calories is " + allowedCalories);
            } else if (c == 4) {
                allowedCalories = BMR * 1.725;
                Console.WriteLine ("Your allowed calories is " + allowedCalories);
            } else if (c == 5) {
                allowedCalories = BMR * 1.9;
                Console.WriteLine ("Your allowed calories is " + allowedCalories);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What errors? What did you try to fix them? What does "I'm trying to access the answer from an equation (BMR)" mean?

Comment: Since `BMR` is defined inside of `Main`, it is not accessible outside of that method. You could declare it outside of main, at the class level: `private double BMR = 0;`, which allows all methods inside the class to access it, or you can include it in the method signature of any method that needs it: `static void ProcessChoice(int c, double BMR)`

Comment: Ohh I see the problem, just pass the BMR to the `ProcessChoice` function as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MBR` is declared locally in `main`. You will not be able to use it outside of the `main` method in a direct manner.

There are multiple ways to solve this issue, but since your code consists of a single class (no dependency-injection between classes is necessary), two main ways come to mind:

---

### First way:

You can declare it at a higher scope level (in this case, `MainClass`):

```
class MainClass
{
    double MBR = 0;
    //...
```

This makes the variable accessible to the entire class, including methods in it, which in turn includes `ProcessChoice`.

---

### Second way:

You can pass it to `ProcessChoice` as a parameter:

```
static void ProcessChoice (int c, double MBR) {
    //...
```

and

```
int choice;
do {
    PrintMenu ();
    choice = Int32.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
    ProcessChoice(choice, MBR);
} //...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the BMR value to your ProcessChoice function:

```
    ProcessChoice (choice, BMR);

    static void ProcessChoice (int c, double BMR)
    {
         ....
    }
```

Comment: Considering the use of `MBR`, a better choice (IMHO) would be to declare it at a higher scope. That's why it's the first option I give in [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46899082/1253136). Still, this is a reasonable answer. +1 --- My only suggestion would be to separate the snippets of code into two code-format blocks instead of one, just to avoid confusion. The code snippets are not continuous nor in the same scope, so avoid portraying them as such. 